# using oncleanUp config option in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my protractor configuration file, I am using the onCleanUp option as below:

```
onCleanUp: function(exitCode){

       var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

       child = exec('node somescript.js',function(error,stdout,stderr){
          console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
          console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
          }
       });
   },
```

However I noticed that somescript.js does not get executed. Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer to this eventually.. for those interested:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1182#issuecomment-51898791